# Как можно сделать сокращение ссылок в гугл таблице?

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

Реализую для удобства себе генератор utm меток, столкнулся с проблей, что clck.ru берет в ссылку только одно значение utm_source=

Может был у кого опыт реализации сокращение ссылок в гугл таблице
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a-Ad2289ztkW0N5Gy9WaZ6bal1Kl2WUdkOJM_qhPtvc/edit#gid=0

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Нужно сделать, чтобы бралась ссылка из ячейки, создавалась автоматическая сокращенная ссылка и сохранялась в другой ячейке